# assign cell to 4 categories based on 4 equal part of a max value

Tags: excel, formula

How do i assign a cell value to 1 of 4 catergories (1-4) based on a max value divided into 4 euqal parts.

e.g. max value is 4, then category 1 should be calculated like 1/4, category 2 like 2*(1/4) an so forth...

```
category 1 is the range 0 to <1
category 2 is the range 1 to <2
category 3 is the range 2 to <3
category 4 is the range 3 to 4
```

How is that possible?

Example data

```
a1      category
1.1     2
2.0     3
3.1     4
4.0     4
2.2     2
```

Comment: wouldn work if you had the value of e.g. 0.002 (?)

Comment: not in my either. Typo :o

Comment: Another typo. fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the lookup function to do what you want.  Something like this seems to work:

```
=LOOKUP(A1,{0,1,2,3},{1,2,3,4})
```

There is either a typo or a contradiction in your source data. Is a 3.1 a category 4 (as your rules state) or a 3 (as your example shows).  In my formula, anything between 3 and 4 fall in to a category 4.

Anything greater than a value of 3 gets a category of 4.  The formula is pretty straight forward (if a value is greater than or equal to 0 and less than 1, it returns 1.  If the value is greater than or equal 1 and less than 2, it returns 2, etc).